# XSLT - To remove special character

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove special character and space from content,

```
<litem><para>■ <emph type="bold">Target:</emph> Water</para></litem>
<litem><para>◆ Wound-healing response within the dermis and epidermis via application of heat without creating a traumatic wound</para></litem>
```

The output would be,

```
<litem><para><emph type="bold">Target:</emph> Water</para></litem>
<litem><para>Wound-healing response within the dermis and epidermis via application of heat without creating a traumatic wound</para></litem>
```

I have used this XSLT,

```
<xsl:output use-character-maps="m1"/>    
<xsl:character-map name="m1">
    <xsl:output-character character="■" string=""/>
    <xsl:output-character character="◆" string=""/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

While using above xslt, only special character is getting remove, not unwanted spce. I want to remove character with space. Could you please guide us.

Comment: So what exactly are the criteria for removing a space character? In general you can use regular expressions in XSLT 2 or 3 with the `replace` function or with `xsl:analyze-string` (XSLT 2 and 3) or the `analyze-string` function (XSLT 3) to find and process certain string patterns.

Comment: Hi Martin, I want to remove special character with space. I have tried replace method but it's not given proper output. See my xslt.
<xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '([■  ]+)','')"/>                
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '([◆  ]+)','')"/>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Above xslt is merging the content as shown below.
<litem><para>■<emph type="bold">Target:Target:</emph>WaterWater</para></litem>
<litem><para>◆Wound-healingresponsewithinthedermisandepidermisviaapplicationofheatwithoutcreatingatraumaticwoundWound-healingresponsewithinthedermisandepidermisviaapplicationofheatwithoutcreatingatraumaticwound</para></litem>
Could you please guide us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<xsl:template match="item/para/text()[1][matches(., '^[■◆]\s*')]"><xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^[■◆]\s*', '')"/></xsl:template>` which would only remove any text in the first `text()` child of `para` of `item` if they start with one of those two characters and are followed by optional white space. You might want to adjust the `match` pattern if you want to have the same effect for other text nodes, but the key is using `^` in the regular expression pattern to indicate to only match the start of a string.

Comment: Thanku for your response Martin.